# Custom Post Type archive

Tags: posts, archives, customization

Hey all first off im a WP newbie so go easy!

Ive been searching for a couple of days now to see if I can find the answer to this but cant get anything definitive.

I have a custom post type called 'documents' and a corresponding archive called `archive-documents.php`. When I click on a custom taxonomy it displays my custom posts in the default `archive.php` template.

Rather than trying to explain more here is the code in `functions.php`

```
add_action('init', 'documents_register');

function documents_register() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Documents', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Document', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Document Entry'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Document Entry'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Document Entry'),
    'new_item' => __('New Document Entry'),
    'view_item' => __('View Document Entry'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Documents'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/documents-icon.png',
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'documents' ),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),

  ); 

register_post_type( 'documents' , $args );

register_taxonomy("types", array("documents"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Types", "singular_label" => "Type", "rewrite" => true));
```

}

Comment: have you tried flushing the rewrite rules (by going to the permalinks settings page & clicking save)? also (sorry, this bit isn't an answer to your question, just me being picky!), i find it more logical to follow the convention of naming custom post types using the singular noun (as used in core for "post" & "page"). "type" is also a [reserved term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms) in WordPress so you shouldn't use that for your taxonomy.

Comment: @SimonBlackbourn Thanks so much! Post this as an answer and hopefully OP will mark it as best answer

Answer (score 2):

When you're viewing a Custom Post Type Archive, your `archive-documents.php` template will be used. In your case this is the URL `/documents/`.

When you're viewing a taxonomy term, you're viewing a *Custom Taxonomy Archive*, not a Custom Post Type Archive. If you haven't created one specific to your taxonomy, then `archive.php` (or `index.php`, if `archive.php` doesn't exist) will be used.

You want to create a template named `taxonomy-types.php` to display the posts in your custom taxonomy.

See the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display) for more info.